# Proof of the Ribet's theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curves

My question is very simple :

My goal is to read a proof the proof of the epsilon conjecture proven by Ken Ribet (1986) which is an ingredient of the proof of the Fermat Last Theorem (I want the Ribet theorem not the FLT)

I have undergraduate knowledge in Galois theory, elliptic curves and modular forms. But I did not found any readable documents that gives the minimal prerequistes for the Ribet's theorem.

Is there someone who know if there is a book which proves this theorem ?  Even if it is at a graduate level ! All I want is a clear road to understand this proof :)

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribet%27s_theorem gives a link to a lecture by Kevin Buzzard, maybe you'd find it useful.

Comment: What you want to do is probably not "A clear road to understand this proof". I think  reading just one book before will not work. It seems that one needs  a general and systematical study of modern number theory first.

Comment: Well as you mentioned the road must be very tricky and I know that. Besides, my goal is not to deeply understand the theory. You may find this useless but I only want to understand the proof "line by line". I am willing to learn the "modern algebraic theory". In fact I am looking for a paper telling what to learn first and then. I am an analyst so my knowledge in algebraic number theory is limited ^^

Comment: You need  first to know several concepts very well. Descent (contemporary, sophisticated enough not that of Fermat to demonstrate the impossibility of $a ^ 4+b^4=c^4$), conductor of an elliptic curve, modular form, level and weight of a newform, Galois representation and others. Without the full understanding of each of these notions is not possible to understand modern topics relating to Fermat's theorem (of worth for themselves, of course).

Comment: Thank you Piquito. I will start learning what you mentioned !